# Date / time control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform app that calculates the time difference between two dates and then
give it back in the format number of days, total hours, total mins.

My markup code is the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" CssClass="label">Resolved Date</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"      TextMode="Date" OnTextChanged="TextBox14_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now the ontextchanged event will calculate the time difference from another date time textbox.

I have done something like this:.

```
protected void TextBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get date from first text box

    DateTime dold = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime dnew = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox14.Text);
    TimeSpan daydif = (dnew - dold);
    double dayd = daydif.TotalDays;
    Label27.Text = dayd.ToString();
}
```

My problem is that whenever there is no output for it? label27 does not have diff of days values.

Is there any other event trigger that I am not aware of?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "But my problem is that whenever there is no output for it? " what does it mean?

Comment: "But my problem is that whenever there is no output for it? ", Just add a String.IsNullOrEmpty check and show a default value in the label?

Comment: You need to initiate a post-back to the server, otherwise the code on the server will never be run.  Try adding `AutoPostBack="True"` to the `<asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Any reason you're not using a calendar control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Jon Skeet I would use the calendar controls for this purpose, you will run into Input validation problems with a text field, with the calendar you are working with a Date object. First you can add your calendar fields to the page.

```
<!-- Old Date -->
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
<!-- New Date -->
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" OnSelectionChanged="TextBox14_TextChanged" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

Then in your onchanged method you can calculate the timespan like so in 1 line, no sense in creating another object double to hold your total days when you can access it like so.  Unless you are going to use it many places then perhaps create a holder double.

```
protected void TextBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Might add some quick validation to make sure a date is selected in both calendars.
        // Not sure if you are subtracting old from new or new from old but you can sorta that out
        Label20.Text = ((TimeSpan)(Calendar2.SelectedDate - Calendar1.SelectedDate)).TotalDays.ToString();
    }
```

Keep in mind when the onselection changed is called the page is being refreshed cause that data has to be submitted to the page in order for server side processing to happen.  Web page events do not work like winforms.